# Combining DataArrays in an xarray Dataset

Tags: python, python-xarray

Is there a nicer way of summing over all the DataArrays in an xarray Dataset than

```
sum(d for d in ds.data_vars.values())
```

This works, but seems a bit clunky. Is there an equivalent to summing over pandas DataFrame columns?

Note the `ds.sum()` method applies to each of the DataArrays - but I want to combine the DataArrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you want to sum each data variable as well, e.g., `sum(d.sum() for d in ds.data_vars.values())`. In a future version of xarray (not yet in v0.10) this will be more succinct: you will be able to write `sum(d.sum() for d in ds.values())`.

Another option is to convert the Dataset into a single DataArray and sum it at once, e.g., `ds.to_array().sum()`. This will be less efficient if you have data variables with different dimensions.